# Узнать строки в  DataGrid, в которых DataGridCheckBoxColumn отмечен

Tags: wpf

Есть элемент DataGrid, который содержит столбец типа **DataGridCheckBoxColumn**, этот столбец будет отмечать пользователь. Как узнать строки в которых данное поле отмечено?

```
   <DataGrid Name="dgv"AutoGenerateColumns="False" >   
          <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Выбрать"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название"></DataGridTextColumn>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну у Вас же есть источник данных для `DataGrid`? Если это коллекция классов, то можно воспользоваться `LINQ`. Как-то так:

```
var checkedItems = sourceCollection.Where(x => x.IsChecked);
```

где `sourceCollection` - данные, которые отображаются в `DataGrid`, а `IsChecked` - свойство класса, которое отображается на `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`

Comment: Наверное я не совсем точно объяснил. В общем ситуация такая - есть некая коллекция, которая отображается в DataGrid. Далее я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог выделить в DataGrid нужные ему строки. Ну и потом, соответственно мне нужно узнать какие строки выделил пользователь, чтобы в дальнейшем обработать объекты, которые в них представлены. Свойство IsChecked в коллекции, которая отображается в DataGrid, заводить не хочу, подскажите как тогда лучше поступить в моей ситуации?

Comment: Это неверный подход. В рамках `WPF` лучше использовать `MVVM`, а значит во `ViewModel`, которая отображается на строку должно быть поле `IsChecked`