# Необходимо получить массив выбранных DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Пользователь отмечает необходимые строки. Мне нужно считать массив id отмеченных. Не отмеченные не интересуют

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("USE BD_THREAT SELECT NAME, SOURSE_OF_THREAT, OBJECT_OF_INFLUENSE FROM THREATS", cn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cn.Open();
da.Fill(ds, "THREATS");
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkboxcolumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkboxcolumn.HeaderText = "";
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(dataGridView1.ColumnCount, checkboxcolumn);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["THREATS"];           
cn.Close();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Лучше добавьте булеву колонку в DataTable.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Опишите чуть подробнее, в чём возникает проблема. Вам нужно подсказать, как считывать данные из DataGridView? Решение, на самом деле, достаточно простое. Нужно привязать данные к DataGridView и добавить колонку `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` по аналогии с вопросом по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/q/2047778/13123688. Таким образом, вам не нужно будет работать с данными из DataGridView. Вы будете работать с данными из BindingList. С помощью `Linq` выбираете то, что вам нужно. Пример: `SomeBindList.Where(x => x.IsEnabled is true)`.

Comment: Здравствуйте, нужно подсказать. Я добавила колонку DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. Не совсем понимаю, как перевести данные в BindingList.

Comment: Тут похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/337345/ , но не могу перевести данные в нужный тип

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работайте напрямую с `DataGridView`.
Вы же используете привязку данных, вот и работайте с `DataTable`.

Имеется поле:

```
private DataTable threats;
```

`DataSet` не нужен, т. к. вы используете одну таблицу.
Загружаем данные:

```
threats = new DataTable();
da.Fill(threats);
```

Добавляем в `DataTable` булеву колонку:

```
threats.Columns.Add("Check", typeof(bool));
```

Делаем привязку. Булева колонка будет отображаться в гриде в виде чекбоксов.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = threats;
//dataGridView1.Columns["Check"].HeaderText = "";
```

При желании можно изменить текст заголовка.

---

Теперь копируем отмеченные колонки в новый `DataTable`.

```
var selected = threats.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<bool?>("Check") == true);

if (selected.Any())
{
    var result = selected.CopyToDataTable();

    // Убираем булев столбец, если он не нужен.
    result.Columns.Remove("Check");

    // Как-то используем выбранные данные.
    // Например, привязываем к другому гриду.
    dataGridView2.DataSource = result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!